# PayPal Express Checkout in native iOS app

Tags: ios, paypal, express-checkout

I need to integrate Express Checkout in my iOS application.
I know that the new Paypal iOS SDK doesn't support Express checkout.
Is there a different library for this purpose, is there a way to integrate express checkout within a `UIWebView`?

I need to send PAYMENTREQUEST_n_PAYMENTREQUESTID, i don't know if i can send it with iOs SDK.

Comment: Did you have a look at [Braintree](http://braintreepayments.com/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question directly, you should be able to use [Mobile EC](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECOnMobileDevices/) within your UIWebView. However, is there a specific feature you are looking for with EC that's not available with the mSDK?

Comment: I need to send PAYMENTREQUEST_n_PAYMENTREQUESTID, i don't know if i can send it with iOs SDK.

Comment: That specific field, no. If you're using it just to send a unique identifier for the payment, you can use 'invoice' or 'custom' with the mSDK.  However, if you are using it in conjunction with Parallel payments then that wouldn't work as Parallel payments are not supported with mSDK.